# When are the data for new Stack Exchange sites added to the Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer, stackexchange-2.0

I like http://data.stackexchange.com, but I am curious about when are the newly launched Stack Exchange 2.0 sites add to the data there. Now that [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) have been launched, why are they not available in the Data Explorer?

Comment: The data on the site is always (at least) a month old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data Explorer should be updated by Feb 10th. That's when new sites will be added to the list.