# Where can you discuss or ask for comments on a data explorer query?

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I ask questions about data explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107137/where-do-i-ask-questions-about-data-explorer)

I am starting to use the Data Explorer. I would like comments and suggestions about a recent query I saved there (I will give the permalink in comments if some people want to, but I don't want to mix a usage question with its application). I noticed that there is no meta.data.stackexchange.com. I have not been able to find a chatroom dedicated to it.

What is the right place to ask for this?

- Here at meta.stackoverflow.com? (But most questions I have seen here about data explorer report bugs or feature-requests)
- In a chat room of meta.SE?
- In the meta of the SE site with which I first tested this query?
- In a chat room of the same SE site?
- Elsewhere?

Comment: I'd say meta is the best place to ask such a question.

Comment: @alex: Thanks for your comment. I will wait for several other reactions before posting my question.

Comment: meta is just fine for this... tag it data-explorer

Comment: I disagree about the proposed dupe. That question is about "how does SEDE work?" questions. This question is about "how's my SQL?" questions, where the SQL just happens to be running on SEDE.

Comment: This question is different to referred http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107137/where-do-i-ask-questions-about-data-explorer.  However it is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52887/notify-contact-sede-user-of-fix-to-query and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56513/data-explorer-needs-the-ability-to-comment-on-queries?lq=1

Answer (score 8):

After further exploration and test :-) and as the upvoted comment shows, the main answer seems to be

- **Here at meta.stackoverflow.com**

So it is quite natural I answer my own question. I try to make it as a little FAQ for newbies like me:

---

**How to discuss queries you make up or modify on the Data Explorer?**

1. You can post a separate question here on meta.SO but know that:
2. There a few notable posts as examples, some suggest to branch to, comment or piggyback when asking about those things (queries in D Ex):

   - [Interesting Queries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer).
3. Make sure that you read some post giving a few nice tips such as:

   - [How to have the date of the current DEx dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80221/in-the-data-explorer-can-you-get-the-date-time-of-the-last-data-update-to-use-in)
4. Don't bother to ask for or complain about the update frequency, freshness of the data or number of sites covered. So many have done that before you. [ex1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-are-obsolete), [ex2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77016/when-are-the-data-for-new-stack-exchange-sites-added-to-the-data-explorer)
5. Very nice external contributions to code and features:

   - [Adding Execution Plans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78050/data-explorer-merge-request-execution-plans)

and now my [own query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91222/new-altruist-moderator-query-spreading-the-badges) as well.

---

People have remarked it would be great to have a [**comment feature for queries**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56513/147111) on the Data Explorer pages itself. Upvote it if you feel the same.

---

I may add that in contrast with other SE sites, the Data Explorer pages do not keep the preferences of the tab/order you want to the list (you are always presented the "favorites" order when you speak on the main top "Queries" link. You have to manually select, say, "Recent" thereafter.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking about a Data Explorer **query**, as opposed to the Data Explorer itself, then your question is probably really about SQL. Questions about SQL are on-topic on Stack Overflow proper, regardless of whether the SQL is for a personal project, SEDE or your production DB at work.

Of course, asking one that *is* about SEDE gives you the rare opportunity to use the [stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com) tag correctly. For an example, see [How can I use two SEDE (SQL) queries as the inputs for a third query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986461/how-can-i-use-two-sede-sql-queries-as-the-inputs-for-a-third-query).

This is not to say that you can't ask SEDE query questions on Meta Stack Overflow. Both locations are considered acceptable. I personally expect SO to have a deeper pool of SQL experts, though (the frequent presence of Tim Stone on Meta aside).