# New Altruist Moderator Query : Spreading the badges

Tags: discussion, badges, voting, data-explorer, moderation

I have started to use that nice tool, [DataExplorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=recent), yesterday.

I would like to have comments and suggestions about this [Badge oriented Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/s/1367/spreading-the-badges-posts-close-to-be-nice-good-great-etc-for-low-rep-user)

Its purpose is to list **posts which are close to the threshold** required for a given badge
so that altruist users can vote them up (or view them or favorite them) and award
the badge to deserving answers or questions.

To help Moderators **motivate new and active users**, by default the query lists posts only
if the potential recipient has less than 3000 rep.

A direct link to the original site is provided in the first column to check the post
and act accordingly if suitable.  It can be handy for user regularly hitting the daily vote limit and wanting to maximize the effect of their votes.

The [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/s/1367/spreading-the-badges-posts-close-to-be-nice-good-great-etc-for-low-rep-user) is configured for the English.SE site but the query seems to work for
any regular SE site available on Data Explorer.

If reaction is good, I plan to make an equivalent query for meta.x.sites, badge definitions being different.

Among the feedback I would like to receive here:

- Have I misinterpreted certain badge definitions?
- How could I check efficiently for the conditions on "Enlightened"?
- Could I have done some part of it more efficiently?
- Do you think some of these queries should be included in moderator or review tools?
- Is there some info column I should add to help make the decision to click or not?